# Jquery Ajax not calling the success Method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a Jquery Ajax that does not call success method, it calls only error Method

Here is the Jquery Ajax:

```
<script>
   function load_timeline_chart(indicator, entity_id, parentid, indicator_title, datatype){
     $.ajax({
         type:       'POST',
         url:        '<?php echo base_url() ?>entities/get_hf_timeline_chart',
         data: {indicator_id:indicator, entity_id:entity_id, parent_id:parentid,quarter:$(".hf_performance_timeline_period.active").find("a").data("quarter"),year:$(".hf_performance_timeline_period.active").find("a").data("year"),data_type:datatype},
         dataType:   'json',
         beforeSend: function(rep){
            $('#entity_timeline_chart').html('<p class="well well-sm text-info"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg"></i>Loading...</p>');
         },
         success: function(rep) {
            alert("success");
         },
         error: function(rep) {
           alert("error");
         }
     });
   }
   </script>
```

Here is the method called from the controller:

```
public function get_hf_timeline_chart()
  {
    echo '{"key1": "value1","key2": "value2","key3": "value3","key4": "value4"}';
  }
```

I checked in the console and I can get the Json from the controller as responce. and the status code is 200.

Could someone help me on this, I struggled a lot on this but didn't find the solution. thank you

Comment: What's in the JS/network console?

Comment: use `console.log("success:"+rep)` and `console.log("error:"+rep)` and check the console to see what's going on

Comment: Have you try to use `jQuery.ajax().done` yet?

Comment: Status code: 200 OK,

Comment: @QuyTruong not yet, could you please show me in my case How to use it? thank you

Comment: @LordNeo I'm getting this in console "error:[object Object]"

Comment: @hakif then you're failing on the call (i mean, the function wasn't even able to get a response from the link, neither good or bad response), check the link trying to be called and check that object returned. bear in mind that php and js may see way different folder structures (absolute in php vs relative in js)

Comment: Is your server sending data as *Content-Type: application/json*? If not, modify the response headers accordingly with *<?php  header('Content-type:application/json'); ?>*

Comment: @LordNeo that's not true. He's getting into error handler for the **$.ajax**, problem is that the first parameter is an **xhr** object so casting this to string results wtih **[object Object]**, for proper logging **console.log("error", rep);** should have been used

Comment: @nizzik don't mind what's rep, it's going straight into the error function, so it's never reaching the target link (either because the link is malformed or it's getting some denied header).

Answer (score 0):

According to Jquery documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR. `jQuery.ajax` is Promise like so you can use callback on it.
In your case, you could change to this:

```
 $.ajax({
     type:       'POST',
     url:        '<?php echo base_url() ?>entities/get_hf_timeline_chart',
     data: {indicator_id:indicator, entity_id:entity_id, parent_id:parentid,quarter:$(".hf_performance_timeline_period.active").find("a").data("quarter"),year:$(".hf_performance_timeline_period.active").find("a").data("year"),data_type:datatype},
     dataType:   'json',
     beforeSend: function(rep){
        $('#entity_timeline_chart').html('<p class="well well-sm text-info"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg"></i>Loading...</p>');
     }
 }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
     alert("success");
 });
```